# Sharepoint Solution dependency (prohibit installing solutions based on dependencis)

Tags: sharepoint-2010

is it possible to make sharepoint solutions depended? For example:

I have a core app solution named -> myapp.wsp
I have a second solution which includes a logging class -> mylogging.wsp.

I would like to prohibit installing the myapp.wsp when the mylogging.wsp is not installed.

Is this possible? Or do i have to create a custom deployment script?

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an activation dependency, you add an ActivationDependencies element inside
the top-level Solution element with a nested ActivationDependency element. Therefore, the
 manifest.xml file in `myapp.wsp` should be updated to look like this:

```
<ActivationDependencies>
   <ActivationDependency 
       SolutionId="<//-- Solution Id of your myLogging.wsp --//>"
       SolutionName="mylogging.wsp"
   />
</ActivationDependencies>
```

For more info : https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/solution-activation-dependencies-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Hi Jatin, tahnks for response. I know about the ActivationDepencies. What i searching for is an "installation" dependency so that th user will be prompted at installation that a pre-requisite is not available.

Comment: HI @BOG, SharePoint by default gives error message if you try to deploy the solution without deploying its dependent solution.